# Query not using index depending on COUNT parameter

Tags: mysql, myisam

First, I create a simple database with one MyISAM table with an indexed field called `feature`.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE test;
USE test;
CREATE TABLE data(
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    feature VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO data VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b');
CREATE INDEX data_feature ON data(feature);
```

Then, when I test a `GROUP BY` query with a count, it doesn't use the index when the `COUNT()` is made by id (see `Extra` column at the end of the `EXPLAIN`).

```sql
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT feature, COUNT(1) FROM data GROUP BY feature;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | data  | NULL       | index | data_feature  | data_feature | 259     | NULL |    2 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT feature, COUNT(*) FROM data GROUP BY feature;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | data  | NULL       | index | data_feature  | data_feature | 259     | NULL |    2 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT feature, COUNT(id) FROM data GROUP BY feature;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | data  | NULL       | index | data_feature  | data_feature | 259     | NULL |    2 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I have tested it on MySQL Community 8.0.21 and MariaDB 10.3.25.

Comment: *it doesn't use the index* No. It uses index (see "key") column. Simply it thinks it's pointless to fill "Extra" because counted column is an index expression.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(id)` obligates the Optimizer to check `id` for being `NOT NULL`.  The standard pattern is to simply say `COUNT(*)`.

InnoDB probably works differently.  But this is because the `PRIMARY KEY` is implicitly tacked onto the end of any secondary index.  That makes `INDEX(feature)` work like `INDEX(feature, id)`, in which case it would be a "covering" index as indicated by "Using index".

(There is virtually no reason to stick with MyISAM in this decade.)

Comment: Perhaps your opinion is a bit gratuitous, without at least asking why.

Comment: @dkretz - Opinion about moving away from MyISAM?  There are many discussions on this forum about it.  In summary:  InnoDB is as good or better in virtually every way.  Crash protection is an important one.  Oracle is trying to get rid of MyISAM.  (It may survive longer and get at least some maintenance from MariaDB.

Comment: And, I added info about InnoDB because virtually everyone on this forum is using InnoDB; they might get confused without my emphasizing that it is a difference between the Engines.  I started this a decade ago, when the migration was looking inevitable:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb